# Coluna responsiva

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um site Wordpress para fazer manutenção e estou enfrentando um problema responsivo. Tenho 2 colunas, "conteúdo principal" e "sidebar":

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 content">

<!-- CONTEÚDO PRINCIPAL -->

</div>

<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">

<!-- CONTEÚDO SIDEBAR -->

</div>

</div> <!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .col- -->
```

O Problema é que quando a resolução é menor a div do **conteúdo principal** continua com 9 parece, pois ele não preenche `full width`. Para vocês darem uma olhada http://vicporai.fatcow.com/ ... Os textos deveriam preencher a largura, como os 3 banners do topo e os títulos dos posts.

ACHO QUE O PROBLEMA É EM `.row` POIS QUANDO DESABILITO O `width:100%` NO INSPECTOR DE ELEMENTO, PARECE QUE FICA FULL...

Tentei de tudo, mas nada adianta. Estou super atrasado com o prazo desse site por causa desse "erro"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o conteudo de seu site que utiliza `bootstrap` ocupe toda a largura do browser troque `class=container` por `class=container-fluid`.

Voce colocou somente um `col` para `sidebar` e 3 para `content`, ficará desproporcional quando o tamanho for menor já que os `md`, `xs` e `sm` são baseado em pixels.

Esteja certo que a estrura do HTML deva seguir basicamente este formato

```
  <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="conhecimentos" class="col-md-8">
                </div>
                <div id="resumo" class="col-md-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Veja o link novamente. Irei trocar para ver